# Cucumber features/Rspec with third party oAuth API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, rspec, cucumber

I am using cucumber and RSpec for my new ruby on rails application and will be using some third party oAuth APIs to send/retrieve data.  I am fairly new to both cucumber and RSpec and have never had to implement third party functionality like this before.  What is the best way to handle this from a spec and feature writing perspective?  I know I shouldn't be querying the services directly, because I can't spec for them being up or down, etc, so I'm sure I will need to stub/mock some objects/functions.  Any help in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a gem called [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) and stub out the requests with results that I know are good.
You can also automatically record requests with [EphemeralResponse](https://github.com/sandro/ephemeral_response), but I haven't used that yet.